# HTTP request using Apache with proxy

Tags: java, apache, http, curl, request

I need help with a connection through a proxy. I know how to add the credentials in the proxy header but I also need to add a sessionid value in the proxy header.

This is the CURL connection that I have to convert to Apache HTTP.

```
curl https://www.google.com
  --proxy https://xxx.xxxxx.com:13128 
  --proxy-header 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx' 
  --proxy-header 'sessionid: xxxxxxx.xxxx' 
  -o /dev/null
```

I'm using this code but I don't kwow how to insert de sessionid value in the proxy header.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
new AuthScope("xxx.xxxxx.com", 13128),
new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("https://www.google.com", 443, "https");
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("xxx.xxxxx.com", 13128);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Any kind of help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to prepare a [CookieStore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) which you need to set in the HttpContext which you in turn pass on every Http request. [detail](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setCookieStore(org.apache.http.client.CookieStore))

Also FYI- DefaultHttpClient is deprecated, CloseableHttpClient is being used now.